# How can I setup a pair of virtual serial ports in windows XP?

Tags: serial-port

I would like to create a pair of virtual serial ports that have a virtual null modem cable between them.

Comment: Ended up using com0com and checking the "emulate baud rate" setting on both virtual comm ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) (Null-modem emulator). It does exactly what you're trying to do, and is fairly simple to use.